# How to find duplicates in each column using its cell value in Excel using VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I want to find the duplicates and highlight it in each column of the active worksheet in Excel 2010 using the cell value specified by us. For instance, There are 5 columns namely "S.No","ID","Name","Desc", and "Amount" which is default all the time (Note: Column value is always same whereas column number may differ each time). So, In this case, I want to find duplicates based on column value. If column X="S.No" then, find duplicates and highlight it.. and/or if column X="ID" find duplicated and highlight it.

I have a code with me, but this works only for column A. Please help me in providing the updates to find all the duplicates in every column in the active worksheet as explained above.

```
Sub DupEntry()
Dim cel As Variant
Dim rng As Range
Dim clr As Long
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Set rng = Range("A1:A" & Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Row)
rng.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
clr = 3
For Each cel In rng
If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rng, cel) > 1 Then
If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("A1:A" & cel.Row), cel) = 1 Then
cel.Interior.ColorIndex = clr
clr = clr + 1
Else
cel.Interior.ColorIndex = rng.Cells(WorksheetFunction.Match(cel.Value, rng, False), 1).Interior.ColorIndex
End If
End If
Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```

Comment: why you use vba for such task?

Comment: Coz, generally we retrieve data from excel for our work and in most of the cases it has some duplicate values. so I thought of simplify the task by using vb macro to automate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve the desired effect by using "Conditional Formatting" feature in Excel Worksheet:

1. Select Column A
2. Click on Conditional Formatting menu button, then select "Highlight Cells Rules" and "Duplicates Values": specify the color from Drop-Down list.
3. Repeat the same steps for other Columns.

In case you prefer to use your VBA solution which highlights duplicates with different colors, then just apply it to other Columns: see that line

```
Set rng = Range("A1:A" & Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Row)
```

so, instead of Column "A" use Column "B", etc. I would recommend to use iteration through the specified Columns range. With minor changes it can be implemented as shown in the following sample code snippet:

```
Sub DupEntry()
Dim cel As Variant
Dim rng As Range
Dim clr As Long
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

'Sample Array of Columns
Dim Col(1 To 3) As String
Col(1) = "A"
Col(2) = "B"
Col(3) = "C"

'Iterate through Columns
For i = 1 To 3
    'Set rng = Range("A1:A" & Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Row)
    Set rng = Range(Col(i) & "1:" & Col(i) & Range(Col(i) & "1048576").End(xlUp).Row)
    rng.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
    clr = 3
    For Each cel In rng
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rng, cel) > 1 Then
            'If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("A1:A" & cel.Row), cel) = 1 Then
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range(Col(i) & "1:" & Col(i) & cel.Row), cel) = 1 Then
                cel.Interior.ColorIndex = clr
                clr = clr + 1
            Else
                cel.Interior.ColorIndex = rng.Cells(WorksheetFunction.Match(cel.Value, rng, False), 1).Interior.ColorIndex
            End If
        End If
    Next
Next i
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```

(original code lines are commented off). Alternatively, you can use cells `R1C1` notation.

Hope this will help. Best regards,

Comment: I want to highlight each duplicate values with different color.. one duplicate value should not  be similar to the other duplicate value

Comment: I understand; see the amended answer. Best regards,

Comment: Thank you Alex, Can we apply this in a single Iteration which covers all the  columns? For eg. range between A and Z in a single line of code ? 

Thanks in advance for your suggestions.

Comment: I have added an iterative solution. If you are satisfied with the answer, please mark it as accepted. Best regards,

Comment: Thank you soo much Alex!

 Its working good as what I expected!! Could you please suggest me how to highlight the duplicates in the same way, but based on the column Value. For eg., Column A1 has the value "ID", B1 has "Name", C1 has "Title". I wanna highlight the dups if column x1 is ID or Name alone. ("x" may be any column in the active worksheet).

 Sample code is below. I dont know how to proceed further since I'm a beginner to vbscript. It's also fine if you append your code to the previous one.

I would be very thankful to you if you do this for me.

Comment: I am glad it's working for you. If you have more questions, please post them separately (not in this comments thread: it's getting too lengthy). Kind regards,